# Redshift Query CPU time

Tags: memory, amazon-redshift, cpu, cpu-usage

I am trying to fetch the `query_cpu_time` value from `SVL_QUERY_METRICS` table in Redshift. But I want the date and time also for all the queries. Is there any system table or solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [SVL_QLOG](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVL_QLOG.html) table and create a join with SVL_QUERY_METRICS on column `query`.

```
SELECT t.starttime,
       t.endtime,
       m.query_cpu_time
FROM   svl_qlog AS t
       JOIN svl_query_metrics AS m
         ON t.query = m.query
```